# with no gravity or friction, would a wheel ever stop rotating

Tags: kinematics

If placed in "space", 1000 light years from any other mass/gravity, would the a rotating wheel with a reflective surface, ever slow or stop rotating?

Comment: Is your wheel on a bearing or is it a spinning disk? Does it have any net charge or is it perfectly neutral? Is it absolutely symmetrical or is the mass distribution uneven? Do we count space as perfect vacuum or do we assume the real density of interstellar matter? There are least four loss mechanisms that could exist in space...

Comment: I should have been a bit more specific in the question. I envision a disk "perfect" in shape and mass distribution, located in space. Indeed, I'm asking what would be any loss effects.

Answer (score 6):

Infinity is a long time. Some of the effects that may be in play:

There are about 50 particles per cubic meter in space. As these particles hit the disk they will take away a small net angular momentum after each collision (assuming they arrive with random directions).

These collisions may cause ionization of the disk. Once it has uneven charge distribution it will start emitting EM radiation (circularly polarized, that will carry away angular momentum).

Any accelerating mass would emit gravitational waves. At the scale of your disk these will be tiny but I believe they must be non-zero.

So there you have it. Three loss mechanisms that will exist even in deep space. I suppose that over the age of the current universe they would not have affected your disk too much. But infinity is a long time.

It might be fun to calculated how long it would be before a realistic disk would lose 1% of its angular momentum due to the above...

Comment: This is making me sad.... Not only we will die eventually, but even a spinning wheel without friction in deep space will stop someday.

Comment: `Any accelerating mass emits gravitational waves` This is something new to me. So basically, everything tries to resist acceleration?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal see http://web.mit.edu/klmitch/classes/8.224/project/gravwave.html